# List Python Packages included in a wheel in a PySpark Job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, python-packaging

I am submitting my Spark job using `spark-submit` CLI with `--py-files` (wheel file) as an argument. I want to list all the packages included in the wheel file either in Driver or executor side. How can I find that ? Tried with `spark.sparkContext._jsc.sc().listJars()`, however its giving only the java jars, not the python packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the .whl files submitted through --py-files by accessing the SparkFiles root directory. Here's a minimal example to achieve that. Assuming this is your spark-submit,

```
spark-submit \
  --master "local[4]" \
  --py-files "/Users/lol/code/pyfilestest/whl-0.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl,\
/Users/lol/code/pyfilestest/dir2path-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl" \
  list_wheels.py
```

(in this example case i have added `dir2path-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl` and `whl-0.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl`)

This script, `list_wheels.py`that is running via spark-submit will print the list of .whl files submitted through --py-files, enabling you to confirm what packages have been uploaded.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkFiles
import os
import glob

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext()

    # List all wheel files in SparkFiles root directory
    sparkfiles_dir = SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()
    wheel_files_with_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(sparkfiles_dir, '*.whl')) 
    # Get only the file names 
    wheel_files = [os.path.basename(file) for file in wheel_files_with_path]
    print("wheel_files:",wheel_files)
```

End result:

a lot of verbose logging and at the end:

```
wheel_files:['dir2path-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl', 'whl-0.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl']
```

NB. In case you want to see what is *in* the wheel files as well then you can change your script to:

```
import os
import glob
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkFiles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext()
    
    # List all wheel files in SparkFiles root directory
    sparkfiles_dir = SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()
    wheel_files_with_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(sparkfiles_dir, '*.whl'))

    for wheel_file in wheel_files_with_path:
        print(f"Listing contents of {os.path.basename(wheel_file)}:")
        
        # Open the wheel file as a ZIP archive and list its contents
        with ZipFile(wheel_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
            for filename in zip_ref.namelist():
                print(f"  - {filename}")
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help :)